# onPause() after locking device during Media Play

Tags: android, media, user-experience, onpause

This is more of a UX perspective question but also Android.

1. Say I'm playing a video using an app such as YouTube and then I press the home screen / lock button.
2. After unlocking the phone, the media does not resume as it is in a pause state.

My questions for the above is:

**What is the benefit of pausing/not pausing?**

**Is there a huge difference in terms of battery consumption. Or more of a subjective question, what do you believe to be a better user experience?**

**How hard is it in general to implement it so that the media resumes after unlocking?**

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

> What is the benefit of pausing/not pausing?

Video? Well I'd say, for example in youtube, once you open the app back up again (after watching a video), you're not always looking to resume your video, but rather navigate to another video. So having it automatically play would be kind of obnoxious.

> Is there a huge difference in terms of battery consumption. Or more of a subjective question, what do you believe to be a better user experience?

Not necessarily; I think would be annoying.

> How hard is it in general to implement it so that the media resumes after unlocking?

```
@Override 
protected void onResume(){
     //call your video resume method
     super.onResume();
}
```